# Google Charts (or other JS visualization framework) line graphs with different styles/colors within the same line

Tags: javascript, linechart, google-visualization

Imagine I am drawing a line chart that includes both known (certain) values and estimated (uncertain) values. These values are all in the same series (not two different lines). This chart of projected population growth rate is a good example: [image: File:World population growth rate 1950–2050.svg]

Notice how after the year 2012 or so, the line turns blue.

I have read the [Customizing Lines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines) page but it appears to change the style for the *entire* line, not just a segment of it.

My question is this: is it possible change the style and/or color of *part* of a line within the same series?

Solutions, in order of desirability:

1. Indicate in the value itself whether or  not it is an exact or an estimated value, and to change the styling for that line segment accordingly (e.g. `[(45, "exact"), (50, "exact"), (75, "estimated')]` although more likely `"exact"` and `"estimated"` would be replaced with `1` and `0` respectively).
2. Data and styling instructions are sent to the API separately, but for the same series.
3. Least desired solution is one where I actually create two different series, because that will mean creating (and keeping track of) two series for each row of data, and generating the code that splits them up into the series, as well as making sure no points are displayed where there should not be data for that series.

Although I would prefer Google Visualization for its (relative) simplicity, I have some experience with D3.js and would be willing to use it instead if it is not possible to use Google Visualization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are two solutions I was able to find:

### Using DataTables and the "Certainty" role

Using DataTables with [roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) allows you to use data values as chart modifiers rather than actual chart data points. In this case specifically the role to use is "certainty". You supply it as an additional column after the data, and indicate that that column is a certainty role, like so:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.
data.addRows([
    ['2014-12-01',100, true],
    ['2015-01-01',200, true],
    ['2015-02-01',300, true],
    ['2015-03-01',400, true],
    ['2015-04-01',500, false]
]);
```

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.
    data.addRows([
        ['2014-12-01',100, true],
        ['2015-01-01',200, true],
        ['2015-02-01',300, true],
        ['2015-03-01',400, true],
        ['2015-04-01',500, false]
    ]);

        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9 },
          curveType: 'function',
          pointSize: 7
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Note that you cannot control the rendering of an "uncertain" section of the line graph — Google decides this for you. If you want more control — for example, if you want it to change color as well or instead of becoming dashed, you can use styling as described below.

## Styling the *line* of a point

Also, although not at all explicit in the [Customizing Points](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) page, you *can* specify styling for the *line* for a point as well as the point itself. If you want more customization over the styling of a segment (say its thickness or its color) you can use this option:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'style'}); // style col.
data.addRows([
    ['2014-12-01',100, null],
    ['2015-01-01',200, null],
    ['2015-02-01',300, null],
    ['2015-03-01',400, null],
    ['2015-04-01',500, 'line { stroke-color: purple }']
]);
```

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'style'}); // style col.
    data.addRows([
        ['2014-12-01',100, null],
        ['2015-01-01',200, null],
        ['2015-02-01',300, null],
        ['2015-03-01',400, null],
        ['2015-04-01',500, 'line { stroke-color: purple }']
    ]);

        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9 },
          curveType: 'function',
          pointSize: 7
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

As far as I can tell you can change the color only; you can't adjust the width or the type of dashed line.